# comparing a string 1-d numpy array elementwise

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I have two 1-d arrays (a and b) containing strings, which I want to compare element wise to get output c like shown below. I tried converting it to set and comparing, however that does not give the correct solution. Also logical_xor does not work for string. I can write a loop to do this but then it defeats the purpose of using arrays, What can be the best way to do this without a loop?

```
  >>  a
      array(['S', 'S', 'D', 'S', 'N', 'S', 'A', 'S', 'M'], 
          dtype='|S1')
  >>  b
      array(['T', 'I', 'D', 'N', 'G', 'B', 'A', 'J', 'M'], 
          dtype='|S1')

  >> c 
     array([False, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, True], 
      dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the ndarray's __eq__ method, i.e. ==

```
>>> a = array(['S', 'S', 'D', 'S', 'N', 'S', 'A', 'S', 'M'], dtype='|S1')
>>> b = array(['T', 'I', 'D', 'N', 'G', 'B', 'A', 'J', 'M'], dtype='|S1')
>>> a == b
array([False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Aah! missed the simplest option ... Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.equal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html#numpy.equal)  :

```
import numpy as np
c = np.equal(a,b)
```

Or [`numpy.core.defchararray.equal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.equal.html#numpy.core.defchararray.equal) :

```
c = np.core.defchararray.equal(a, b)
```

**EDIT**

`np.equal` has been [deprecated in the last numpy's releases](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/release.html#id50) and now raises a `FutureWarning`:

```
>>> c = np.equal(a,b)
__main__:1: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
>>> c
NotImplemented
```

The equality operator `==` will suffer the same fate as `np.equal`. So I suggest using:

```
c = np.array([a == b], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: This does not work. You get the error: ```FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
NotImplemented```

Comment: Ok this is a deprecation of numpy (see [this stuff](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#id50)). I edit my answer :)

Comment: This post should be the selected response.