# How to call the default string equality function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators, equality

I would assume:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array(["a", "b", "c"])
print(a == "abc")
print("abc" == a)
```

to output

```
[False False False]
False
```

, because the latter comparison should use the definition of equality for strings and the former should use the definition of equality for NumPy arrays.

The real output is:

```
[False False False]
[False False False]
```

Why does this happen[1] and how would one prevent it[2]?

[1] I.e. why is `str.__eq__` `NotImplemented`?

[2] I.e. how can one call the equality check that was performed if `np.ndarray.__eq__` would not be implemented?

[Edit] This question was marked as possible duplicate to [comparing a string 1-d numpy array elementwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247003), which it is not, because there the exact opposite is asked (basically how to use `np.ndarray.__eq__`), and neither [1] nor [2] are discussed at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [comparing a string 1-d numpy array elementwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247003/comparing-a-string-1-d-numpy-array-elementwise)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give a quick rundown of what's happening:

The `'abc' == a` expression will invoke `'abc'.__eq__(a)` first, but `str.__eq__` will  return `NotImplemented` if passed an argument not of `str` type. As a fallback, Python will invoke `a.__eq__('abc')` instead. The reason behind delegating the comparison to the reflected method on the other object is because that object might actually implement it.

In this case, `np.array.__eq__` can actually handle strings, by doing an element by element comparison, and returns `[False, False, False]`. As per the [data model docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__), this is accepted: `__eq__` methods needn't return a `bool` value. This behavior will occur regardless of the position of the variables in the equality.

Now, to answer your questions specifically:

- Why is `str.__eq__` `NotImplemented`?

That's simply the expected behavior of `str.__eq__`, as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) states:

> Objects of different types, except different numeric types, never compare equal

In other words, `str.__eq__` is only implemented for `str` arguments. Comparing `str` types to other objects of different types would require some sort of implicit type conversion, which would go against the Zen of Python:

> Explicit is better than implicit

- How can one call the equality check that was performed if `np.ndarray.__eq__` would not be implemented?

If both sides of the equality didn't implement `__eq__`, Python will do a final fallback to `id(a) == id('abc')` which will compare the addresses in memory of both objects. This will return just `False` as each `id` call will return an `int`, which will be different for each object. So, you could use `id(a) == id('abc')` if that's what you need.

Comment: Default string comparison is not comparison by id: `a = "abcd"[0:3]; b = "abc"; print(a == b); print(id(a) == id(b))` e.g. prints `True\nFalse`.

Comment: Both `"abcd"[0:3]` and `"abc"` are `str` types and default string comparison with string arguments is `str.__eq__`. No `id` comparison will occur. The `id` comparison fails because it's comparing addresses in memory which may or may not be the same for immutable types like strings (for example: single char strings will have the same `id`: `id("abcd"[0]) == id("a")`).

Comment: Ah, `str.__eq__` only gives `NotImplemented` for non-string types! That explains it to me. Thank you.